# How to break C source code in R?

Tags: c, r

I want to set a a break-point in the C implementation for model.matrix. I tried Selva's solution in [How can I view the source code for a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function/32990381?noredirect=1#comment53911068_32990381):

```
> debug(C_modelmatrix)
Error in debug(C_modelmatrix) : object 'C_modelmatrix' not found
> debug(modelmatrix)
Error in debug(modelmatrix) : object 'modelmatrix' not found
```

The function I'm interested can be found [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b156e3a711967f58131e23c1b1dc1ea90e2f0c43/src/library/stats/src/model.c).

```
SEXP modelmatrix(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP rho
```

I'm building and running from R source code. How do I set a break-point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is still-useful video tutorial by Seth Falcon on [how to debug R packages with native code](https://vimeo.com/11937905) which shows this.

In essence, launch `R` with `R -d gdb` to invoke the `gdb` debugger which you then instruct to set breakpoints in the right places.

If you (or your operating system) prefers a different compiler, you *obviously* need to substitute it in the invocation: `R -d lldb`.

Answer (score 2):

I think Dirk's answer is perfect. Note that gdb is not supported in OS-X, we'd have to use lldb.

```
> /bin/R -d lldb
> b modelmatrix
> r
```

Now, run any one-factor ANOVA experiment to trigger the breakpoint.

Comment: That's a comment and not an answer.